# Why does my algorithm to output every digit of a sum fail In PTA?

Tags: java, algorithm

I wrote some code to solve the problem below. I have trid some test cases and they all pass, but when I submit my answer for automatic marking, the result is a fail. I have no idea where is the problem.

Here is the problem and the corresponding [link](https://pintia.cn/problem-sets/994805342720868352/problems/994805519074574336):

1005 Spell It Right （20 分)
Given a non-negative integer N, your task is to compute the sum of all the digits of N, and output every digit of the sum in English.

Input Specification:
Each input file contains one test case. Each case occupies one line which contains an N (≤10^100​​).

Output Specification:
For each test case, output in one line the digits of the sum in English words. There must be one space between two consecutive words, but no extra space at the end of a line.

Sample Input:

```
12345
```

Sample Output:

```
one five
```

Below is my codes(It needs to replace the class name to be Main before submit to system):

```
package com.maxim.advance;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.close();
    int length = input.length();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        sum += input.charAt(index) - '0';
    }
    // Consider sum == 0 case;
    if (sum == 0) {
        System.out.print("zero");
    }

    String[] names = new String[] {
            "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"
    };


    List<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String> (100);
    while (sum > 0) {
        outputs.add(names[sum % 10]);
        sum = sum / 10;
    }


    int size = outputs.size();

    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i > 0) {
            System.out.print(outputs.get(i) + " ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(outputs.get(i));
        }

    }
}
}
```

**The C++ codes below are correct and pass always**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string s;
cin>>s;
long int tmp=0;
for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
    tmp+=(s[i]-'0');
}
string match[10]={"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
vector<string> v;
long int sum=tmp;
while(sum){
    v.push_back(match[sum%10]);
    sum/=10;
}

reverse(v.begin(),v.end());
if(tmp==0)// 
cout<<"zero";
else
for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
    if(i==0)
    cout<<v[i];
    else
    cout<<" "<<v[i];
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a test case that you know will fail?

Comment: you might try Big Integer or long long int in place of int,since the range of N is 10^100

Comment: @Johan Sorry, I can't, all the local test case are pass, so I am confused.

Comment: @anupam691997 Is it true? Suppose the range of N is 10^100, then the maximum of sum is 9 * 100, declare it as int type is enough, isn't it?

Comment: I tried with input `9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999` (one less than 10^100). The output was `nine zero zero` as it should be. I also tried with 10^100 (1 one and 100 zeroes) and got `one`.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with algorithm for solving the core problem. I'm wondering if perhaps the issue is the way in which the unit tests are passing input to your code and/or the way they are reading the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggestion from a net friend, it pass after I remove package statement, which is really weird.